# How do I get DOM element by mouse click on PyQT5 QWebView

Tags: python-3.x, dom, qwebview, onmouseclick

I have simple application based on PyQT5.
I need to get DOM element that is under mouse cursor when the mouse button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Will answer myself:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.view = QWebView(self)
        self.view.installEventFilter(self)
        # create other components here


    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj == self.view:
            if (event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease):
                htc = self.view.page().mainFrame().hitTestContent(event.pos())
                e = htc.element()
                if e:
                    #do somesing with e
                    return True
        return  QMainWindow.eventFilter(obj, event)
```